# Delta Method and Expected Value

Tags: statistics

I would just like to check something regarding the delta method.
After using the delta method to verify that,

$$
\sqrt(n)(g(X_n)-g(\mu)) \sim n(0,\sigma^2 [g\prime(\mu)]^2)
$$

we **cannot** generally assume that assume that $E(g(X_n))=g(\mu)$, right? Under what conditions would this be true?
Thanks.